# How to interact with Amazon bought items?

Tags: amazon-product-api, kindle

I would like to synchronize our library management system (OLIB) with our Amazon's account in order to keep track of our bought eBooks. Is that even possible? The closest I've got is Amazon's Product Advertising API:

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

However it seems to work with Amazon's product list but there is no mention about how to access my account to manage my purchased Kindle eBooks.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I am starting to hack a screen scraping API just to be able to manage my kindle a bit more efficiently, but I would love to have something working already.

Comment: **oligofren:** Unfortunately, I have not seen anything close to what I was looking for. u_u

Comment: Have started trying to reverse engineer some kind of API to make fetching and deleting items possible, but I cannot get the basic posting to the service right. I can manipulate things once logged in with Chrome, but using those same cookies and parameters just sends me to the login screen when trying to use Curl. Any ideas? Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004781/unable-to-replicate-query-to-amazon-manage-kindle-using-curl-what-am-i-missing

Would you be keen on contributing if I put this up on GitHub?

Comment: Check out my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.  There's a slightly longer answer at a related question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12905025/1251108.

In general Amazon does not seem interested in exposing customer purchase history.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but not officially. You can probably build something on top of the work I have done. So far I have exposed functionality for

- listing bought content
- listing personal documents (stuff you have emailed or Instapaper deliveries)
- deleting items

You can [find my code on GitHub](https://github.com/fatso83/amazon_fiona) - published just a few minutes ago :) Be aware that this works by emulating a browser, and as such will be very fragile to changes in the UI. But Amazon has not changed anything since I complained to them several years ago, so I would not worry too much ...